# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out при обращении к localhost

Tags: java, servlet, tcp

Имеется программа которая считывает данные по протоколу `ModbusTCP/IPv4` (На данный момент работаю с эмулятором slave ус-ва). При запуске программы как обычного приложения (`public static void main`) всё работает нормально- данные считываются. Но если данные выводить в браузер с помощью `HttpServlet` то после считывания и вывода, на высокой скорости, некоторого количества данных всё время ловлю `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`.

Запускать пробовал через `Tomcat` и `Jetty` - везде одно и тоже. 
Контроллер принимающий данные выбранные для отображения:

```
 @WebServlet(name = "param", urlPatterns = {"/param"})
public class GetParametrsServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
List list = null;
Map map;



protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    System.out.println(session.getMaxInactiveInterval());
    list = Arrays.asList(request.getParameterValues("a"));
    String ip = (String) request.getAttribute("ip");
    request.setAttribute("list", list);
    map = ChooseRegisters(list);
    session.setAttribute("map",map);
    response.sendRedirect("View_Result.jsp");
    System.out.println(list);


    if (ip == null){
        session.setAttribute("error_ip","Не корректный ip адресс");
    }



}

protected void doGet(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
}



public HashMap ChooseRegisters(List list) {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("3205", "Motor_Torque");
    map.put("3204", "Motor_Current");
    map.put("3208", "Motor_voltage");
    map.put("3211", "Motor_power");
    map.put("9630", "Motor_thermal state");
    map.put("7393", "Fault_counter");
    map.put("7270", "DC_bus_voltage");

  Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){

        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        if(map.containsKey(entry.getKey())!=list.contains(entry.getKey())) {
            iterator.remove();

        }
    }
    return (HashMap) map;
}
}
```

Класс для работы по `ModbusTCP`:

```
public class Test_Read {

TCPMasterConnection con = null;
ModbusTCPTransaction trans = null;
ReadMultipleRegistersRequest request = null;
ReadMultipleRegistersResponse response = null;
ReadInputRegistersRequest readInputRegistersRequest = null;
ReadInputRegistersResponse readInputRegistersResponse = null;
InetAddress addr = null;
final int port = 502;
HashMap map_values = null;
HashMap response_map = null;





public HashMap CheckValues(HashMap map, TCPMasterConnection con) {

        map_values = new HashMap();
        response_map = map;
    System.out.println("Fresh map is come" + response_map);
            Iterator iterator = response_map.entrySet().iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    try {
                        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                        request = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(Integer.parseInt((String) entry.getKey()), 1);

                        trans = new ModbusTCPTransaction(con);
                        trans.setRequest(request);
                        trans.execute();
                        trans.setRetries(10);
                        response = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
                        System.out.println(response.getRegisterValue(0));
                        map_values.put(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()), String.valueOf(response.getRegisterValue(0)));
                    } catch (ModbusException e ){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }
    return map_values;
}





public void ConnctionTo(String addres) throws Exception {
    addr = InetAddress.getByName(addres);
    con = new TCPMasterConnection(addr);
    con.setPort(502);
    con.setTimeout(1000);
    con.getTimeout();
    con.connect();
}

public void Disconnect(TCPMasterConnection con){
        if(this.con.isConnected()){
            con.close();
        } else System.out.println("Нет подключения");
}

    public TCPMasterConnection GetConnection(){
        if(con.isConnected()){
            return con;
        }
        else return null;
    }
}
```

Контроллер для вывода результата:

```
@WebServlet(name = "show_Registers", urlPatterns = {"/show_Registers"})
  public class Show_Registers extends HttpServlet {
Test_Read T_read = null;
Gson builder = new GsonBuilder().create();

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, SocketTimeoutException {

        T_read = new Test_Read();

        try {
            T_read.ConnctionTo("127.0.0.1");
            TCPMasterConnection con = T_read.GetConnection();
            System.out.println(con.isConnected());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Something wrong");
        }


        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if ((session != null) && session.getAttribute("map") != null) {
            HashMap map = (HashMap) session.getAttribute("map");

            try {
                HashMap Complete_map = T_read.CheckValues(map, T_read.GetConnection());
                System.out.println(Complete_map);
                String JSON = builder.toJson(Complete_map);

                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                response.getWriter().write(String.valueOf(JSON));

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException ignored) {
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Код js:

```
function show_Value()
{


function MapObject(Motor_Torque,Motor_Current,Motor_voltage,Motor_power) {
    this.Motor_Torque = Motor_Torque;
    this.Motor_Current = Motor_Current;
    this.Motor_voltage = Motor_voltage;
    this.Motor_power = Motor_power;
}


$.ajax({
    url:'show_Registers',
    success : function(responseText) {
         var mapobject = new MapObject(responseText);



        var s = responseText;
        var map = String.valueOf(responseText);
        alert(mapobject.Motor_Current + " " + mapobject.Motor_Torque);

        $('#MyFuckingMap').text(s);
       setTimeout(250,show_Value());
    }
});
}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransport.readResponse(ModbusTCPTransport.java:171)
at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:193)
at ConnectionToDevice.Test_Read.CheckValues(Test_Read.java:51)
at servlet.Show_Registers.doGet(Show_Registers.java:47)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:833)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:243)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusIOException: Executing transaction failed (tried 3 times)
at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:197)
at ConnectionToDevice.Test_Read.CheckValues(Test_Read.java:51)
at servlet.Show_Registers.doGet(Show_Registers.java:47)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:833)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:243)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

И вот если в   `setTimeout(250,show_Value());` установить значение в 3-4 секунды то всё работает. Также стоит сказать что через какое-то время он продолжает работать и получать новые значения.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вероятно, в коде работы с устройством возникают ошибки при работе в многопоточном окружении. Точно сказать невозможно, без полного текста ошибки и кода.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, Спасибо за отклик. Информацию добавил

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем, проблемы решил. Данное исключение возникало в следствии того, что каждый раз вызывая аджаксом сервлет - я создавал новое подключение к эмулятору. Решил проблему хранением connection в сессии.